# Opportunity visibility in reports

Tags: opportunity

There are 10 opportunity : 8 can be viewed by given role & permission.. but remaining 2 are confidential and different set of people or group should be able to see those confidential opportunities and these opportunities are not visible in reports.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want any difference in visibility between users, you need to start with setting the Organization-Wide Sharing Setting for that particular object to 'Private'. That will make the Opportunities visible only to their Owner.

After that, you can use sharing rules (based on owner, role, opportunity fields, etc) to share records with the correct groups of people (roles, public groups).

More info here: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_getstart_how_does_the_sharing.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the link:
https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=admin_sharing.htm&siteLang=en_US
On this page You can find a note which can help.

Note:If Grant Access Using Hierarchies is deselected, users that are higher in the role or territory hierarchy don’t receive automatic access. However, some users—such as those with the “View All” and “Modify All” object permissions and the “View All Data” and “Modify All Data” system permissions—can still access records they don’t own.

So make a new role high above who would be able to access Opportunities of the roles(users assigned) under it.